# Find the ciphering method 4

Tags: cipher, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

[Link to the entire series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A85112%20title%3A%22Find%20the%20ciphering%20method%22).

The message:

```
A U J A H M N Q G B U B A W Q W Q M Q R 
N W N G Q G P U M S T Z A N G U O W R M 
R L H M O W O P W N X Z R U O T X U X I 
N K N W M N B A B H E O W P M M O H T G 
P Y A G G Y H S Y K N G Q U Y A Z J P G 
Y W M N Y R E Y K K U W Z W B E Y S J B 
R R C Y R Z H O Y M P C O X T M X V U P 
Y W M O Z K E S P B Q W Q E S Y T N M B 
R W Z N P R U B J E M G O Q F A B U A O 
W R A H B K T O Z B S Q K M U H A J E N 
K Q R N R Z R A O J O T F J K Z Q N S A 
O W K Q P A M M F A P A F B W R G F J F 
M D M R Z M G L U X B E X M V Z T W I U 
Y S A M G Q N Z K H U U U Y F R Y Z P W 
E R D B S R O F A A F X B B O X I U X J 
E U G J T W T H N Y E Z S Z Y Y Z Q E Z 
M L Q X R N T I W S E R B G V R M G N Q 
N N W F B U M Q T T H N O R N W H U J J 
U A S G E E M E K O Z S P T M T O A B S 
N A Q B N K Y P B T G H W U M W O N M N
```

The answer:

> FLUTE

Hint 1:

> Look at row composition

Hint 2:

> Some rows have letters that others do not have.

Hint 3:

> X marks the <s>spot</s> row. And not only X.

Comment: Given how quickly you are coming up with them, it might be better if you were to ask all questions in a single interconnected puzzle. Just saying though.

Comment: @newQOpenWid - thank you, I will consider doing it in the future. However, I will leave the first 4 as they are because deleting and republishing them would be unfair to those who have already started solving one of them and doesn't want to solve others.

Comment: People post partial answers where they only solve one puzzle, btw.

Comment: All rows have letters that others do not have. There is no letter that appears in every row. The least frequent letters `ILVDC` are all associated with Roman numerals.

Comment: @codewarrior0 - yes, the puzzle employs all Roman numerals except M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption method was to:

1. Start with the input
2. Apply a ROT3 Encryption
3. Convert the characters to A1Z26
4. Square the A1Z26
5. Convert the A1Z26 to roman numerals
6. Embed the roman numerals in the crossword

Table of steps:

| ROMAN | ARABIC | SQRT | A1Z26 | ROT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LXXXI | 81 | 9 | I | F |
| CCXXV | 225 | 15 | O | L |
| DLXXVI | 576 | 24 | X | U |
| DXXIX | 529 | 23 | W | T |
| LXIV | 64 | 8 | H | E |

Image with highlighted characters:
[image: Crossword grid with Roman Numerals highlighted]

Comment: That seems to be a correct answer. One difference with my method is I used Ceasar cipher with the shift of 3 instead of ROT4, but apparently they are identical? Also, may I ask what software you used to highlight the letters?

Comment: @webadventurer Right, I had used A0Z25. Updated. I highlighted the characters with Excel.